# datatables attributed required false not working as intended

Tags: javascript, php, datatable

I am trying to set the certain fields in the form to allow null values to be submitted which I have attempted to do by setting `required: false`.

But it still keeps returning the field error indicating that those fields are required.

```
{
    label: "Clock In",
    name: "clock_in",
    "defaultContent":"null",
    attr: {
            required: false
          }
},
{
    label: "Clock Out",
    name: "clock_out",
    "defaultContent":"null",
    attr: {
             required: false
          }
},
```

[image]

Comment: Are you using a Javascript form builder?

Answer (score 0):

Its been a long time I have used datatables, what I remember is there is validation method we need to invoke while instantiating field like below

```
Field::inst( 'clock_in' )->validator( Validate::notEmpty(  false ) )
```

Comment: where do i write this line of code though? it causes an error in my javascript